# What is self() in python?

Tags: python, self

I thought I understood `self` on some pretty decent level. But I came across this:

```
    for f in flags:
        if f not in flagMap:
            raise error.Error('bad debug flag %s' % (f,))
        self._flags = self._flags | flagMap[f]
        self('debug category \'%s\' enabled' % f)
```

What does `self(...)` do?

Comment: It calls `self.__call__`

Comment: Basically the `<name>()` will call `<name>.__call__` and this is true also for `self`. To this extent, this is more of a standard behavior than a specific `self` thing.

Comment: Btw, there's nothing special about ``self``, it's just a variable name as any other. It's just a **convention** to use ``self`` as the first parameter in instance methods to reference the instance.

Comment: See also: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__call__.  And for a contrived example: https://pastebin.com/nREereJX

Comment: `self` is just a variable, it is not special syntax. It depends entirely on what `self` *is* here. If it is an instance of a custom class, look for a `__call__` method.